# onsenuiがユニットテストでエラーが発生する

Tags: onsen-ui, jasmine

onsenuiを使用したハイブリットアプリを作成しています。

Karmaとjasminを使用してユニットテストをしたいのですが、
テスト実行時に下記のエラーが発生します。

```
Error: isWebView() method is available after dom contents loaded.
```

onsenuiはangularJSでDIしています。

```
  var appModule = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);
```

回避方法ご存知であればお教えください。

Answer (score 1):

`ons.isWebView()`をスパイして常に`true`を返すようにするといいです。

```
describe('OnsenUIのテスト', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn(ons, 'isWebView').and.returnValue(true);
  });
  it('テストサンプル', function() {
    // ここにテストを書く
  });
});
```